# Repeating a mouseover rotation every time it is moused over

Tags: javascript

I am working in the DOM, trying to get this mouseover event to keep repeating itself everytime I mouse over. Currently it only does the rotation on one mouseover, but if I mouseover it again it does not do it again. Here is what I am working with

```js
const allPics = document.querySelectorAll("img")
allPics.forEach((pics) => {
    pics.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        pics.style.transform = "rotate(360deg)";
        pics.style.transition = "transform 1s";
    })
})
```

Comment: My only idea is to try to add another event listener for `mouseout` to reverse the movement, and maybe that'll essentially 'reset' the `mouseover` event listener? Or maybe you should use `mouseenter` instead? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseenter_mouseover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions animate a value from one value to another. In this case you are telling the element to animate the `transform` value over 1 second.

On the first mouseover, you set the transform to 360 degrees. Its current transform is 0 degrees. Over the next 1 second, it transitions from 0 to 360 degrees, thus the animation. At the end of the transition however, the value stays at 360 degrees. This is why future mouseover events don't animation. Transitioning from 360 degrees to 360 degrees in 1 second results in no animation.

Here is one potential solution using transitions.

```
var isAnimating = false;

avatar.onmouseenter = function() {
  // Let the previous animation finish
  if (isAnimating) {
    return;
  }

  isAnimation = true;
  avatar.style.transform = "rotate(360deg)";
  avatar.style.transition = "transform 1s";

  // In 1 second, reset the transform back to 0 (but don't animate it)
  setTimeout(function() {
    avatar.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
    avatar.style.transition = "";
    isAnimating = false;
  }, 1000);
};
```

Another option is to use Animations instead of Transitions. Animations have some nice additions like not resetting the values after the animation ends, replaying an animation multiple times, etc....

For example this solution keeps the image spinning while hovered and paused when the mouse leaves. You'd have to add some more complexity to get the image to finish its final rotation but its a start.

```
<style>
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
</style>
<script>
var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
avatar.style.animationName = "spin";
avatar.style.animationDuration = "1s";
avatar.style.animationIterationCount = "infinite";
avatar.style.animationPlayState = "paused";

avatar.onmouseenter = function() {
  avatar.style.animationPlayState = "running";
};

avatar.onmouseleave = function() {
  avatar.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
};
</script>
```

Comment: I liked your first solution, and was trying to work it into my code...but I am sorta new at this and wasn't sure where I'd place the isAnimating var, in regards to my code as I am using queryselectors and what not

Comment: Ah, nvm my comment, I figured out where it goes and I used your first solution for my code and it worked! Thanks a lot for the help!